# Laravel: InsertgetId and display results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to insert some records into my DB table and using the insertgetid feature, return those results to my blade view.

Controller

```
    $grids[] = array();

    foreach($c as $key) {

    $grids[] = DB::table('infile')->insertGetId(
        array(  'href' => $key, 
                'creator_id' => $id,
                'random' => substr(str_shuffle("aBcEeFgHiJkLmNoPqRstUvWxYz0123456789"),0, 9))
    );
    }

    $name[] = array();
    foreach($grids as $id){
    $name = DB::table('infile')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
    }

    return View::make('Home')->withName($name);
```

Blade View

```
@if(isset($name) && $name != '')
                {{dd($name)}}
                @endif
```

I'm getting this error

```
ErrorException

preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereIn` to make exact query. `between` should work, but it's error prone, since there might be another row inserted in the meantime:

```
$ids = [];

foreach (..)
{
   $ids[] = DB::table('infile')->insertGetId(...);
}

$data = DB::table('infile')->whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a different approach

I found the max `id` before I performed the insert and then found the max `id` after the insert and then used a wherebetween to grab the data.

```
$max = DB::table('infile')->max('id');

foreach($c as $key) {

    DB::table('infile')->insertGetId(
        array(
            'href' => $key, 
            'creator_id' => $id,
            'random' => substr(str_shuffle("aBcEeFgHiJkLmNoPqRstUvWxYz0123456789"),0, 9)
        )
    );
}

$max2 = DB::table('infile')->max('id');
$data = DB::table('infile')->whereBetween('id', array($max, $max2))->get();
```

Comment: I see it's pretty old, but anyway I I'll comment that. I would not recommend do it such a way. What if your max is 100, but your AUTOINCREMENT value of the table is 250? Your approach is good for some ideal situation when you don't have any exception. And what will be if you have more than 1 process writing data into DB?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $id = DB::table('user')->insertGetId(['name'=>"test"]);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given (indeed, your approach seems to be mentioned in the accepted answer already). You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.